# How do I, using a macro, decrease all the values in a selected range by 1

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I've searched for similar questions, but the problem I'm having is that I'm adding what I'm looking for to an existing recorded macro that uses commands like:

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select

to select a range.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the `Counta` function, assuming there aren't any blanks in the data. I also added `IsNumeric` in case the value is text. If you wanted to go a step further to make sure everything is neat, you can add this right before the `If` statement:

```
Sub Minus_One()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Cells As Range

Set Cells = Sheets(WhateverSheet).Range("A1:A" & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")))

For Each Cell In Cells

If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) = True Then Cell.Value = Cell.Value - 1

Next Cell

End Sub


Cell.Value = Trim(Cell.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Set rngTarget = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Set rngTarget = Range(rngTarget, rngTarget.End(xlDown))

    Dim rngIndex As Range

    For Each rngIndex In rngTarget
        With rngIndex
            .Value = .Value - 1
        End With
    Next rngIndex

End Sub
```